# Oracle Identity Manager - add attribute to OUD provisioning

Tags: ldap, oim

I'm struggling with the customization of the provisioning of an identity from OIM to an OUD server as target resource.

I've been able to perform the provisioning with default attributes, the user identity is created successfully and I'm able to use it for the authentication in a Spring web application.
Now I want to add authorization based on the user location. The location of the user is available in OIM, so I want to provision it to the LDAP server in order to avoid to manually edit each identity.

I've searched a lot but I've not been able to add an additional attribute to the provisioning process, up to now I've just modified reconciliation and provisioning lookups in OIM, but this is not enough or either I've made a mistake.

I've found some guides to extend the functionality of the connector but they were related to Active Directory.

Does someone has any advice or a guide to help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty well described in their [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22999_01/doc.111/e28603/extending-functionality-oid-connector.htm#CLDAP501), so from the high level perspective it's:

- you add a new field on the provisioning form
- associate the new form version with the application instance
- make lookup changes to reflect the attribute mapping
- add provisioning tasks to the provisioning process